# one-to-many relationships in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have 2 tables called "twitter_user" and "twitter_comments".

**twitter_users** has the fields: username and bio
**twitter_comments** has the fields: username and comment

Obviously, an user has 1 entry in twitter_users and potentially many in twitter_comments

I want to model both twitter_users and twitter_comments in Elastic Search, have ES search both models when I query, knowing that a comment counts towards the overall relevancy score for a twitter user.

I know I can mimic this with just 1 model, by creating a single extra field (in addition to username and bio) with all the comments concatenated. But is there another "cleaner" way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends.

If you just want to be able to search for a users comments ,full-text and over all fields, simply store all comments within the user object (no need to concatenate anything):

```
{
    "user" : {
        "username" : "TestUser",
        "bio" : "whatever",

        "comments" : [
        {
            "title" : "First comment",
            "text" : "My 1st comment"
        },
        {
            "title" : "Second comment",
            "text" : "My 2nd comment"
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

If you need per-comment-based queries you need to map the comments as [nested](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/nested-type.html) (before submitting any data), so that every comment gets treated as a single item.

For your scoring, simply add another field "comment_count" and use this for your boost/scoring.

Answer (score 2):

As Thorsten already suggested you can use nested query and it's a good approach.

Alternatively, you can index comments as children of users. Then you can can search users as you do now, search comments using [top_children](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/top-children-query.html) query to find all relevant to your search comments, and finally combine scores from both of them together using [bool](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-query.html) or [dis_max](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/dis-max-query.html) queries.

Nested approach would be more efficient during search, but you will have to reindex the user and all comments every time an additional comment is added. With child/parent approach you will need to index only new comments, but search will be slower and it will require more memory.