# Use a many to many relation in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, many-to-many

Currently we have a problem to perform a query (or more precisely to design a mapping) in elasticsearch, which help us to perform a query over a relational problem, that we didn't get solved with our non-document orientated thinking from sql.

We want to create a many-to-many relation between different Elasticsearch entries. We need this to edit an entry once and keep all using’s updated to this.

To describe the problem, we'll use the following simple data model:

```
    Broadcast           Content
   ------------        ---------
    Id                  Id
    Day                 Title               
    Contents []         Description
```

So we have two different types to index, broadcasts and contents.
A broadcast can have many contents and single contents could also be part of different broadcasts (e.g. repetition).

JSON like:

```
index/broadcasts
    {
        "Id": "B1",
        "Day": "2014-10-15",
        "Contents": [
            "C1",
            "C2"
        ]
    }
    {
        "Id": "B2",
        "Day": "2014-10-16",
        "Contents": [
            "C1",
            "C3"
        ]
    }
index/contents
    {
        "Id": "C1",
        "Title": "Wake up",
        "Description": "Morning show with Jeff Bridges"
    }
    {
        "Id": "C2",
        "Title": "Have a break!",
        "Description": "Everything about Android"
    }
    {
        "Id": "C3",
        "Title": "Late Night Disaster",
        "Description": "Comedy show"
    }
```

Now we want to rename the "Late Night Disaster" into something more precisely and keep all references up to date.

How could we approach this? Are there fourther options in ES, like includes in RavenDB?

Nested objects or child-parent relations didn't helped us so far.

Comment: possible duplicate of [one-to-many relationships in Elastic Search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13427434/one-to-many-relationships-in-elastic-search)

Comment: @nyth nested didn't support many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

What about denormalizing? seems difficult if we come from the SQL mindset, but give you a try, even with millions of documents, LUCENE indexing can help, and renaming will be a batch job.

```
[
  {
    "Id": "B1",
    "Day": "2014-10-15",
    "Contents": [
      {
        "Title": "Wake up",
        "Description": "Morning show with Jeff Bridges"
      },
      {
        "Title": "Have a break!",
        "Description": "Everything about Android"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": "B2",
    "Day": "2014-10-16",
    "Contents": [
      {
        "Title": "Wake up",
        "Description": "Morning show with Jeff Bridges"
      },
      {
        "Title": "Late Night Disaster",
        "Description": "Comedy show"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```